# kafka producer - how to know which key will go to what partition?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-topic

I am aware of `kafka console producer` command and it is quite handy. I want to know is there a way to know for sure which key will go to which partition when we have key as well? Assuming we have 10 partitions in kafka topic, how will producer decide to which partition the key will go?

I thought it might use `key.toString.hashCode() % (num_of_partitons)`, but i don't think this is the way kafka console producer employs.

Can we check to which partition producer will send data to?

Comment: It is not the producers responsibility to distribute messages among partitions.

Comment: The producer does select the partition it is producing to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the default partitioner is used, it will not hash code the keys string value, instead it uses a [Murmur2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MurmurHash) hashing algorithm as seen in the [org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.DefaultPartitioner](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/internals/DefaultPartitioner.java) code:

```
Utils.toPositive(Utils.murmur2(keyBytes)) % numPartitions;
```

The implementation of the algorithm can be found [here](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/common/utils/Utils.java).